# SQL Query Looking for optimisation for complex query with indexes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM $database1 
          WHERE userid!='$userid' 
            AND mediaid NOT IN (SELECT mediaid 
                                FROM $database2 
                                WHERE uid='$userid')
          ORDER BY active ASC LIMIT 80";
```

This query was working very well until now.

That it suddenly takes 0.5 to sometimes even 3s to execute, sometimes it also goes down to 0.1 which is acceptable.

Now `database2` has around 3 millionn rows and `database1` around 500, but it also sometimes is slow when only 100 items in `database1`. I'm worried because `database2` is getting around 30k new rows each day.

Both `mediaid`, `userid`, `uid` are all indexes.

Server? 8cores x 3,2, 16gb ram. Scalable cloud. Average load is fine. not more than 20% cpus

EDIT: Explain Select Returned following data:

```
1   PRIMARY database1   index   userid  active  4   NULL    80  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  database2   index_subquery  uid,mediaid mediaid 130 func    93  Using where
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you provide us with more information about table and constraints. We can't be guessing what's going on without knowing the selectivity of columns as well. Attaching `EXPLAIN` results and `analyze()` of the query would help a lot as well.

Comment: I have updated, question. Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i have re-writed query to download both data for current user id. Then calculate it in php. Now it's quite fast. x10 faster. For now it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the query to a left join

```
select
d1.* from $database1 d1
left join $database2 d2 on d2.mediaid = d1.mediaid
and d2.uid='$userid'
where d1.userid!='$userid' 
and d2.mediaid is null
ORDER BY d1.active LIMIT 80
```

The following indexes would be needed as well, change the `database1` and `database2` to real table names

```
alter table `database1` add index ua_idx(userid,active);
alter table `database1` add index mid_idx(mediaid);
alter table `database2` add index u_mid_idx(mediaid,uid);
```

Comment: I have already added indexes like
"ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `mediaid` (`mediaid`(128))"
Before indexing it was total crap, more than 10s. These informations are after indexing.

Comment: Yes I just added the indexes which will be needed for the query if its already there then you may not need to add them, however note that you are doing an order by `active` and this needs to be indexed as well.

Comment: I have indexed 'active' but it does not really improved performance. I have also used your re-writed sql. But average performance seems the same. Any other hints? It can't be like this.

Comment: use `explain select..` and see what it gives you.

Comment: I have updated question with result of "explain select"

Comment: Yes the explain says you have a depenedent subquery which I changed to a join. And looks like your indexes are getting picked up. You may refactor the query to use join, but for a large data optimizer would choose always the best approach, You can check both queries yours and mine and see which one is better. You also enable the mysql cache for more optimization.

Comment: Both queries results seems pretty the same. Im running on MariaDb

Comment: Also i dont think caching will help since there is different data to display for each userid. So it must check all rows, always anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76278/discussion-between-steven-and-abhik-chakraborty).